# More efficient way to use transform in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

I want to create a new column which counts how many times an IP switches domains.

**Input:**

```
    domain      ip      timestamp              next_domain    next_next_domain
0   Google      101     2020-04-01 23:01:41    Facebook       N/A
1   Google      101     2020-04-01 23:01:59    Facebook       N/A
2   Google      101     2020-04-02 12:01:41    Facebook       N/A
3   Facebook    101     2020-04-02 13:11:33    N/A            N/A
4   Facebook    101     2020-04-02 13:11:35    N/A            N/A
5   Youtube     103     2020-04-21 13:01:41    Google         Facebook
6   Youtube     103     2020-04-21 13:11:46    Google         Facebook
7   Youtube     103     2020-04-22 01:01:01    Google         Facebook
8   Google      103     2020-04-22 02:11:23    Facebook       Youtube
9   Facebook    103     2020-04-23 14:11:13    Youtube        N/A
10  Youtube     103     2020-04-23 14:11:55    N/A            N/A
```

I have the following code which gives me the following output:

```
df['switch'] = df.groupby('ip')['domain'].transform(lambda x: x.shift().ne(x).sum()-1)
```

**Output:**

```
    domain      ip      timestamp              next_domain    next_next_domain  switch_count
0   Google      101     2020-04-01 23:01:41    Facebook       N/A               1
1   Google      101     2020-04-01 23:01:59    Facebook       N/A               1
2   Google      101     2020-04-02 12:01:41    Facebook       N/A               1
3   Facebook    101     2020-04-02 13:11:33    N/A            N/A               1
4   Facebook    101     2020-04-02 13:11:35    N/A            N/A               1
5   Youtube     103     2020-04-21 13:01:41    Google         Facebook          3
6   Youtube     103     2020-04-21 13:11:46    Google         Facebook          3
7   Youtube     103     2020-04-22 01:01:01    Google         Facebook          3
8   Google      103     2020-04-22 02:11:23    Facebook       Youtube           3
9   Facebook    103     2020-04-23 14:11:13    Youtube        N/A               3
10  Youtube     103     2020-04-23 14:11:55    N/A            N/A               3
```

IP 101 switches 1 time because it goes from Google -> Facebook. IP 103 switches 3 times because it goes from Youtube -> Google -> Facebook -> Youtube.

I have the following solution using "transform" but it takes a long period of time to run on my data set.
Is there a faster and more efficient solution that doesn't use transform or apply?

Comment: Can we assume the df is sorted in time? You seem to assume so also in your code if I understand correctly. What about `ip`? Probably not sorted I guess

Comment: data is sorted by date and ip address sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

I think you could calculate the difference beforehand (since anyway you subtract 1). However, this requires the df to be sorted by `ip` and `timestamp` to ensure it works correctly. By doing this outside of `groupby` it should be significantly faster.

```
df['switch_count'] = df['domain'].shift().ne(df['domain'])
df['switch_count'] = df.groupby('ip')['switch_count'].transform('sum') - 1
```

```
      domain   ip            timestamp next_domain next_next_domain  switch_count
0     Google  101  2020-04-01 23:01:41    Facebook              NaN             1
1     Google  101  2020-04-01 23:01:59    Facebook              NaN             1
2     Google  101  2020-04-02 12:01:41    Facebook              NaN             1
3   Facebook  101  2020-04-02 13:11:33         NaN              NaN             1
4   Facebook  101  2020-04-02 13:11:35         NaN              NaN             1
5    Youtube  103  2020-04-21 13:01:41      Google         Facebook             3
6    Youtube  103  2020-04-21 13:11:46      Google         Facebook             3
7    Youtube  103  2020-04-22 01:01:01      Google         Facebook             3
8     Google  103  2020-04-22 02:11:23    Facebook          Youtube             3
9   Facebook  103  2020-04-23 14:11:13     Youtube              NaN             3
10   Youtube  103  2020-04-23 14:11:55         NaN              NaN             3
```